# How to randomise an image array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a image array in which I was wondering before I select an image from it with an id number if I could randomise them so the same image can have a different id number every time the app is run?

My image array:

```
<array name="PairImages">
    <item>@drawable/a</item>
    <item>@drawable/b</item>
    <item>@drawable/c</item>
    <item>@drawable/d</item>
    <item>@drawable/e</item>
    <item>@drawable/f</item>
    <item>@drawable/g</item>
    <item>@drawable/h</item>
    <item>@drawable/i</item>
    <item>@drawable/j</item>
</array>
```

Code I use to fill in my image views with an image from the array:

```
ImageView FirstImageCard, SecondImageCard, ThirdImageCard, FourthImageCard, FifthImageCard, SixthImageCard, SeventhImageCard, EightImageCard;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(getSystemUiFlags());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirstImageCard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    SecondImageCard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    ThirdImageCard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    FourthImageCard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    FifthImageCard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    SixthImageCard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    SeventhImageCard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    EightImageCard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8);

    final TypedArray ImageArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.PairImages);

    FirstImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(0, -1));
    SecondImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(1, -1));
    ThirdImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(2, -1));
    FourthImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(3, -1));
    FifthImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(4, -1));
    SixthImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(5, -1));
    SeventhImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(6, -1));
    EightImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(7, -1));
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pretty much all the work done, you just need an array or list to hold your id values and then randomize them. Take a look at [shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)).

Your code will end up being something like:

```
//...

final TypedArray ImageArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.PairImages);

//Just a holder for random numbers. 
//If you add/remove an image make sure you change the 8...
ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    randomNumbers.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(randomNumbers);
int i = 0;


FirstImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(randomNumbers.get(i++), -1));
SecondImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(randomNumbers.get(i++), -1));
ThirdImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(randomNumbers.get(i++), -1));
FourthImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(randomNumbers.get(i++), -1));
FifthImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(randomNumbers.get(i++), -1));
SixthImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(randomNumbers.get(i++), -1));
SeventhImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(randomNumbers.get(i++), -1));
EightImageCard.setImageResource(ImageArray.getResourceId(randomNumbers.get(i++), -1));

//...
```

You can also try to build your array with random numbers right away with something like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array), but I think the shuffle is alright for now.

Comment: can you do the same with a text box and an array with lets say numbers as the items?